# Adding views in the negative way of a uiscrollview and changing contentsize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIScrollView` with a calendarView in it. What I want now is that the 2 next months and  2 previous months are already loaded inside the scroll view.

I have the two following methods.

```
-(void)addCalendarToEnd{
    iPhoneMonthView *phoneCal =  [[iPhoneMonthView alloc] init];
    phoneCal.delegate = self;
    phoneCal.dataSource = self;
    [phoneCal selectDate:[self sameDateByAddingMonths:1 andDate:scrollDate]];
    float xValue = phoneCal.frame.size.width * numberOfCalendarsAfterToday;
    phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height);
    [self.calendarScroll addSubview:phoneCal];
    int numberScroll = numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday + numberOfCalendarsAfterToday + 1;
    calendarScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberScroll*phoneCal.bounds.size.width,calendarScroll.bounds.size.height);
    [calendarScroll addSubview:phoneCal];
    NSLog(@"CONTENT SIZE IS %f",calendarScroll.contentSize.width);

    numberOfCalendarsAfterToday++;

}
-(void)addCalenderToBeginning{
    iPhoneMonthView *phoneCal =  [[iPhoneMonthView alloc] init];
    phoneCal.delegate = self;
    phoneCal.dataSource = self;
    [phoneCal selectDate:[self sameDateByAddingMonths:-1 andDate:scrollDate]];
    float xValue = phoneCal.frame.size.width * numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday;
    NSLog(@"XVALUE IS %f",xValue);
    phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(-xValue, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height);
    [self.calendarScroll addSubview:phoneCal];
    int numberScroll = numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday + numberOfCalendarsAfterToday + 1;
    calendarScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberScroll*phoneCal.bounds.size.width,calendarScroll.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"CONTENT SIZE IS %f",calendarScroll.contentSize.width);
    numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday++;
}
```

The `addCalendarToEnd` is working like it should. But the `addCalendarToBeginning` isn't. 
It is adding the view on the correct place. But I don't know how I should set my `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`.

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT**

And this is what I'm doing in the ViewDidLoad

```
 scrollDate = [NSDate new];    
    iPhoneMonthView *phoneCal =  [[iPhoneMonthView alloc] init];
    phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height);
    phoneCal.delegate = self;
    phoneCal.dataSource = self;
    [phoneCal selectDate:[NSDate new]];
    NSLog(@"PHONE CALL HEIGHT IS %f",phoneCal.frame.size.height);
    float xValue = phoneCal.frame.size.width * numberOfCalendarsAfterToday;
    phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height);


    calendarScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height)];
    calendarScroll.delegate = self;
    [calendarScroll addSubview:phoneCal];
    calendarScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    calendarScroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(numberOfCalendarsAfterToday*phoneCal.frame.size.width,phoneCal.frame.size.height);
    calendarScroll.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

    [self.calendarView addSubview:calendarScroll];
    NSLog(@"PHONE CALL HEIGHT NOW IS %f",phoneCal.frame.size.height);


    numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday++;
    numberOfCalendarsAfterToday++;
```

Comment: Why are you adding your calendar twice, in `addCalendarToEnd`?

Comment: @mattsven but could you please help me figure it out? I'm looking for a solution for days now !

Comment: This is the order of things you should do to do this on runtime. You should make the previousMonthView. Then add this size to the content size of the scrollview like normal.
Then move all the views on top of the scrollview further down. Then place the previousMonthView on the origin(0,0) of the scrollview. Now you change the contentOffSet of the scrollview to the size of the previousMonthsView so that it seems to the user that you haven't moved at all, except now he can scroll upwards to previous months.

Comment: @StefGeelen, do you require paging?  In other words, require that the scroll view snaps to integral pages?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only 5 months that you wish to scroll through, then I would suggest populating the content in a linear fashion and then moving the content offset appropriately..

So loop through the views adding them to the scrollview and adjusting the origin of the frame so they sit flush with each other.

Then adjust the contentOffset so

```
scrollview.contentOffset.x = 3*phoneCal.frame.size.width;
```

However if you want to scrollview an "infinite" amount that you should have a look at a solution like [DMCircularScrollView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmcircularscrollview)

Comment: It is the second case!

Comment: Try this   scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are making it harder than necessary. If I understand your problem right, you should be able to solve your problem by doing something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    int numberOfMonthViews = 5;
    float monthViewWidth = 320.0f;
    float monthViewHeight = 200.0f;
    self.calendarScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, monthViewWidth, monthViewHeight)];
    self.calendarScroll.delegate = self;
    self.calendarScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSDate* todayDate = [NSDate new];
    int dateOffset = -2;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonthViews; i++)
    {
         iPhoneMonthView *phoneCal =  [[iPhoneMonthView alloc] init];
         phoneCal.delegate = self;
         phoneCal.dataSource = self;
         [phoneCal selectDate:[self sameDateByAddingMonths:dateOffset andDate:todayDate]];
         float xValue = monthViewWidth * i;
         phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, 0, monthViewWidth, monthViewHeight);
         [self.calendarScroll addSubview:phoneCal];
         calendarScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xValue + monthViewWidth, monthViewHeight);
         dateOffset++;
    }

    self.calendarScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(monthViewWidth*2, 0.0f);
}
```

Please do comment if you have any questions to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Begin try to set your scroll view content offset:

calendarScroll.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

Comment: could you please give me some more information? Setting the offset to CGPointZero is not really working for me

Comment: could you tell me what you see in logs of :  what will be the value of x in it ?  phoneCal.frame = CGRectMake(-xValue, 0, phoneCal.frame.size.width, phoneCal.frame.size.height);

Comment: That is wrong it take your view out of screen put 0 instead of -320

Comment: But that's the point. then it is going to overlap with my view I added in the viewDidload

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest doing this the way you're doing them - as it is, I don't seem any control of quantity or reuse, you're going to be creating infinite calendars (literally). I would suggest leveraging existing solutions:

https://github.com/evadne/DayFlow (infinite calendar)

https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView (infinite UIScrollView)

Secondly, setting a negative value for the beginning calendar's frame won't work, it'll just result it it being outside visible bounds. You'd have to give it an origin of `{0, 0}` and shunt all the following calendars to accomodate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `addCalendarToEnd` method you are adding **phoneCal** as a subView of **calendarScroll** first with `self.calendarScroll` and at end with `calendarScroll`.

And in `addCalenderToBeginning` method, you should set `contentSize` such like..

```
calendarScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(-(numberScroll*phoneCal.bounds.size.width),calendarScroll.bounds.size.height);
```

**EDITED :**

Just try with in `viewDidLoad` method

```
int numberScroll = numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday + numberOfCalendarsAfterToday + 1;
calendarScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberScroll*phoneCal.bounds.size.width,calendarScroll.bounds.size.height);
```

and also set `numberOfCalendarsBeforeToday++;` at beginning of the method `addCalenderToBeginning`.

Just try with my above code if any things that you don't understand then put it as comment here.

Comment: The first one was a typo. But when I set the contentsize like you said it is not working ?

Comment: I'm making a calendar app
I have a CalendarView which contains a certain month say for example june
In my viewDidload I also load up the month before june and the month after june
When the user scrolls to the previous month, the month before the previous should be added to the scrollview

Comment: It is not working. But I think you don't understand what i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: can you explain please

Comment: I've explained it 3 comments up. I want dynamically add calenderViews in the UIscrollview and scroll to views that have an Xvalue below 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the `contentInset` parameter to define the scroll limits for the user.

I guess you want to only let them peak at the top calendar, unless they drag enough at which point you'll set the `contentInset.top` to a negative number to "unlock" a new scrolling region and let them scroll further up.